# Why my trac can't run

Tags: apache, python-2.7, trac

I have followed the instructions from the trac official site: [this](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnUbuntu) and [this](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall). But I got these apache2 error logs when I restart the apache2 service:

```
[Wed May 03 11:46:18.641715 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 30937:tid 140202045007744] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed May 03 11:46:19.730816 2017] [:error] [pid 31070:tid 140509321906048] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.6', found '2.7.12'.
[Wed May 03 11:46:19.730936 2017] [:error] [pid 31070:tid 140509321906048] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Wed May 03 11:46:19.730943 2017] [:error] [pid 31070:tid 140509321906048] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/pyth    on2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'.
[Wed May 03 11:46:19.730951 2017] [:notice] [pid 31070:tid 140509321906048] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 6 max processes and 25 max threads.
[Wed May 03 11:46:19.730954 2017] [:notice] [pid 31070:tid 140509321906048] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Wed May 03 11:46:19.746158 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31070:tid 140509321906048] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operatio    ns
```

Some said these errors were just warnings, but my trac didn't run. The browser showed "Unable to connect", anyone could help me to fix, some hints, thanks very much!

My trac version is "trac-admin - The Trac Administration Console 1.2.1"

my VirtualHost is below:

```
    <VirtualHost *:8090>
    #ServerName * 
    #DocumentRoot /mohism_trac
    <Location />
       SetHandler mod_python
       PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
       PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
       #PythonOption TracUriRoot /
       PythonOption TracEnv /var/www/mohism_trac
       # PythonOption TracEnvIndexTemplate /var/local/trac/templates/index-template.html
       PythonOption TracLocale en_US.UTF8
       PythonOption PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp
       #Order allow,deny
       #Allow from all
       Require all granted
       PythonDebug on
    </Location>
    <Location /login>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Mohism Research"
      AuthUserFile /var/www/mohism_trac/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
    </Location>

    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/trac_errors.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/trac_accesses.log" common 
</VirtualHost>
```

After correcting my configs, the error from /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Thu May 04 06:56:15.091624 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23791:tid 140324578609024] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu May 04 06:56:16.170664 2017] [so:warn] [pid 23958:tid 140090664261504] AH01574: module python_module is already loaded, skipping
[Thu May 04 06:56:16.172837 2017] [:notice] [pid 23959:tid 140090664261504] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 6 max processes and 25 max threads.
[Thu May 04 06:56:16.172848 2017] [:notice] [pid 23959:tid 140090664261504] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Thu May 04 06:56:16.186403 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 23959:tid 140090664261504] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_python/3.5.0- Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operati    ons
[Thu May 04 06:56:16.186436 2017] [core:notice] [pid 23959:tid 140090664261504] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Please give your Trac version and share your Apache virtualhosts configuration file content.

Comment: my trac version is :"The Trac Administration Console 1.2.1"

Comment: I have updated the content, thanks!

Comment: What version of Python is returned from `python --version`? Do you have more than one version of Python installed on your platform? I'm guessing that ModPython was built against a different version of Python than you are running. What OS are you running, and how did you build or install mod_python? Unrelated, you should specify only `TracEnvParentDir` or `TracEnv`, and you've specified the latter twice in your config. See [TracModPython](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModPython) for more details.

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# python --version
Python 2.7.12
Previously I used anaconda to manage multiple python versions, now I disabled anaconda, the only 2.7.12 version.
The ubuntu version is:
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: Now I have built the mod_python from source compatible with apache2.4. The python init errors have gone, but tracd still can't be launched by apache2!

Comment: Did you fix the `TracEnvParentDir` / `TracEnv` conflict? Please post your revised virtualhosts config.

Comment: I have updaeted the config, I copied it from https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnUbuntu

Comment: With Apache 2.4 you need `Require all granted` rather than the two lines that precede it.

Comment: The [TracOnUbuntu](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnUbuntu) have not been updated for Trac 1.2.x and Ubuntu 16.04, so the exact config shown on those pages won't work.

Comment: Let me know if/what error you get after changing to use `Require all granted`. You can also try removing the `TracUriRoot` option.

Comment: "Require all granted" is not the key point, I used it previously, it still failed, and I have changed just now, it can't fix my problem. Thanks very much for your replying! But what should I do? The document is the only example config I can reference. Need I have to change to mod_wsgi mode?

Comment: I have updated the content. It seems no apparent errors. Could you tell me where are some other errors logs? related to apache2. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143363/discussion-between-alexunder-and-rjollos).